# How to implement Javascript CustomEvent IE Polyfill

Tags: javascript

I'm having problems understanding how I should be implementing the IE CustomEvent Polyfill. I have CustomEvent working in other browsers but can't seem to get the Polyfill to work.

```
(function () {

    // CustomEvent polyfill
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#Polyfill
    if ( typeof window.CustomEvent === "function" ) return false; //If CustomEvent supported return

    function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
        params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
        var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
        evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
        return evt;
    }

    CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;

    window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;


})();

// CustomEvent supported
// From example: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/custom_events_js.htm

document.body.addEventListener("fontsLoaded", doSomething, false);

function doSomething(e) {
    alert("Event is called: " + e.type);
}

var myFontsLoaded = new CustomEvent("fontsLoaded");
document.body.dispatchEvent(myFontsLoaded);
```

Comment: Replace `doSomething(e)` with `doSomething`. Pass the reference instead of executing the function.

Comment: Thank you, that was a typo in the example code. It doesn't resolve the problem I have implementing the Polyfil.

Comment: I don't know which browsers you need to support exactly but are you sure [`dispatchEvent`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dispatchevent) is available?

Comment: Microsoft Edge supports CustomEvent so the polyfill is for >= IE9. The code from "// CustomEvent supported" down works in browsers supporting CustomEvent. I'm just not sure how I'm meant to implement the polyfill.

Comment: If you have that IIFE in your script it will polyfill `CustomEvent` to browsers who don't have `typeof window.CustomEvent === "function"`. It looks like you are doing it right.

Comment: The code above is working in IE9 and modern browsers. I must have another issue it my main code.

Comment: Can you please let us know which browser you have trouble polyfilling? And are their any errors thrown?